# Can I use observer pattern for error handling?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

Can I use observer pattern for error handling? What are adv/disadvantages of it? Does anybody use this approach for this purpose?

**UPDATE:**

```
class MyErrorApi{
public static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 1;

public(MyErrorApi error){
...
}
}


interface ErrorListener{
void onErrorOcurred(MyErrorApi arror)
}


class MyBaseScreen implements ErrorListener{


void onErrorOcurred(MyErrorApi arror){
swirch(arror){
**showPopup();**
.....
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you had in mind? Error handling is quite a broad subject.

Comment: I think you may find [this](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/1632) article interesting.

Comment: how do you handle errors? do you fix them, log them, rollback to previous state, etc...

Comment: Its best to start with; what is the problem I am trying to solve and then find the best solution.  You shouldn't start with the solution you would like to use and then see if it fits into the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More likely you need a simple callback like [`ErrorHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ErrorHandler.html):

```
public interface ErrorHandler {

    /**
     * Handle the given error, possibly rethrowing it as a fatal exception
     */
    void handleError(Throwable t);

}
```

This is quite common approach - you register a callback method to be notified when exception occurs *somewhere*. However this is not strictly an *Observer* - the state of the target object didn't change, you are only notified about an error that occurred in the target (which, on the other hand, is kind of event).

Also typically you can have more than one *Observer*. It is rare to have more than one error handler, but not hard to imagine.

Comment: In a more complex and online manageable system you might have one that writes logs and one that sends notifications and so on. It might be overly pedantic though.

Comment: This approach can be generalized to EventHandler interface while an Event is passed as an argument to handleEvent method . Then the error information could be passed in event itself ...

Answer (score 3):

The Observer pattern could be used for error **reporting**. Something detects an error condition and emits an ErrorEvent, something else reports the error to a log or management system. That's quite common.

However consider the main flow of your code: you probably need to take different paths

```
fetch customer's details
if customer is a good credit risk
    lend them some money
```

what does your code do if the the customer's details cannot be fetched due to an error? In concept you need

```
fetch customer's details
if the fetch worked AND customer is a good credit risk
    lend them some money
```

there is some level of direct conditionality on not having an error. We might implement that via exception handling or error checking, but however we are doing it we must truly HANDLE the error in our logic.

Now it is possible to design a more event driven system where everything proceeds by responding to events. In that case everything, not just error handling, is done using the Observer pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The observer pattern looks promising if you have one of the following designs (or both):

- We have *one* source that detects *errors* and produces *error notifications*. Then want to allow other (unknown) components to receive those notifications.
- We have *one* central component that can process error notifications and want to have it listen to other (unknown) components that produce *error notifications*.

In other cases we may find designs that fit better.